# Can I alter all columns of table to allow NULL at once in phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table containing 101 columns. Currently all none of them accepting allowing `null` value. I want to alter table and change all the columns at once.

I know it's totally wrong but I want something like this

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ALTER COLUMN * DEFAULT NULL
```

I only know this way by selecting that column I can do it manually

[image]

Comment: You have to do it for every single column. No short-cuts available.

Comment: BTW: having 101 columns in 1 table is a sign of bad database design